# I cant change to faces or edges view!

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

where are the buttons to select faces or edges view gone? loaded factory settings, still not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a mesh, you have a curve that is filled in (i.e. set to 2D curve type).
Curves have no face / edge / vertex options. If you want to convert it to a mesh (something that has vertices and faces) use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select *Mesh from Curve*.